# Reading raw data from an sqlite table in python

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I am currently trying to make a logon system, just to learn some more advanced python script.

Originally, I was using `.txt` files to save all of the information, but that ended up being messy and unsecured.

After I completed the first set of script, I decided to try saving the information to a database file. I have figured out how to read data from the table but it comes out with `[(''),]` around it.

This is an issue because, I need to use the raw data to compare to an input, which cannot be done with the symbols around it.

So, I was wondering if it is possible to read the data as a raw string, without the symbols. I have been doing this in a separate file to the main project. Here is the contents of said file:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

con = sql.connect(r"E:\Users.db")
c = con.cursor()
con.row_factory = sql.Row
username = input("What is your username: ")

readdata = input("Select the message you wish to read: ")
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE '"+readdata+"') AND   (Recipient LIKE '"+username+"')")

component = c.fetchall()

for row in component:
    c.execute("SELECT Recipient FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE '"+readdata+"') AND (Recipient LIKE '"+username+"')")
    rc = list(c.fetchall())
    rec = str(rc)
    c.execute("SELECT Sender FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE '"+readdata+"') AND (Recipient LIKE '"+username+"')")
    snt = list(c.fetchall())
    sent = str(snt)
    c.execute("SELECT Subject FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE '"+readdata+"') AND (Recipient LIKE '"+username+"')")
    sbject = list(c.fetchall())
    subject = str(sbject)
    c.execute("SELECT Message FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE '"+readdata+"') AND (Recipient LIKE '"+username+"')")
    mg = list(c.fetchall())
    msg = str(mg)

    print()
    print("Sender: " + sent)
    print("Recipient: " + rec)
    print("Subject: " + subject)
    print()
    print("Message: " + msg)
```

And here is the output:

```
What is your username: James
Select the message you wish to read: LOL

Sender: [('Kieran',)]
Recipient: [('James',)]
Subject: [('LOL',)]

Message: [('Hey',)]
```

This is all the correct data, but I need to remove the `[(''),]` to be able to compare it. I am using Python 3.4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is bad: you execute 4 times the same request to get 4 attributes, and you are concatenating input data into the query string which can lead to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You should rewrite it like:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

con = sql.connect(r"E:\Users.db")
c = con.cursor()
con.row_factory = sql.Row
username = input("What is your username: ")

readdata = input("Select the message you wish to read: ")
c.execute("SELECT Sender, Recipient, Subject, Message FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE ?) AND   (Recipient LIKE ?)", (readdata, username))

component = c.fetchall()

for row in component:
    (sent, rec, subject, msg) = tuple(row)
    print()
    print("Sender: " + sent)
    print("Recipient: " + rec)
    print("Subject: " + subject)
    print()
    print("Message: " + msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have lists with all rows, each row a sequence of columns. If you expected just *one row*, fetch just one row:

```
rc = c.fetchone()
```

Now you have just a tuple with columns.

You can get the one column with indexing, or using tuple assignment:

```
first_column = rc[0]
```

or

```
first_column, = rc
```

Note the comma there.

You can combine this with the `c.fetchone()` call:

```
first_column_of_first_row, = c.fetchone()
```

You do need to look into using *SQL parameters* to avoid SQL injection (a security issue where an attacker takes over your database) and make it possible for the database driver to optimise queries as you remove the specific data from the query itself. Instead of string concatenation (`'<query part>' + data + '<query part'`) you should use *placeholders* and leave adding quotes to the driver:

```
c.execute(
    "SELECT Recipient FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE ?) AND (Recipient LIKE ?)",
    (readdata, username))
```

Now `readdata` and `username` will be slotted into the places where you put question marks in the query, complete with proper quoting that also handles escaping of quotes in the data itself.

For a `LIKE` query you probably want to include `%` wildcards:

```
c.execute(
    "SELECT Recipient FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE ?) AND (Recipient LIKE ?)",
    ('%{}%'.format(readdata), '%{}%'.format(username)))
```

The `str.format()` calls here add `%` wildcards to the start and end. Without wildcards, you may as well use `COLUMNNAME = ?` instead, as the `LIKE` will only match the whole column value in that case.

Next, since you are retrieving *4 columns* you can just get all 4 of those in *one* query, then extract the results of each row in a loop:

```
c.execute(
    "SELECT Recipient, Sender, Subject, Message FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE ?) AND (Recipient LIKE ?)",
    ('%{}%'.format(readdata), '%{}%'.format(username)))

for rec, sent, subject, msg in c:
    print("Sender: " + sent)
    print("Recipient: " + rec)
    print("Subject: " + subject)
    print()
    print("Message: " + msg)
```

I loop *directly* over the `c` cursor here; the `fetchall()` call is not needed unless you need a list for random access to all rows. Each row consists of exactly 4 columns, because the `SELECT` asked for those, in a specific order, so we can assign those directly to the 4 variables.

Comment: What does the `fetchone()` do? :) And I always do something like `a = c.fetchall() ; a.items()[0]` before.

Comment: @KevinGuan: it fetches just one row, leaving the rest of the results to be fetched later.

Comment: @KevinGuan: see the [`cursor.fetchone()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone). Note that it'll return `None` if there are no more results to fetch.

Answer (score 2):

`fetchall` is an iterator over all the results returned by your query. Using `list` explicitly turn this iterator into a list of its elements. Each element is a tuple containing the columns you’re asking for in your query.

Thus, getting the element you want should be something like `rec = rc[0][0]` or `sent = snt[0][0]` instead of `rec = str(rc)` or `sent = str(snt)`.

However, both your query and the way you are retrieving it can be improved:

```
c.execute("SELECT Recipient, Sender, Subject, Message FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE '"+readdata+"') AND (Recipient LIKE '"+username+"')")
```

will get you all four variable in one query which is more efficient for your database.

Note, however, that using string concatenation to inject parameters into a query is prone to SQL vulnerabilities. Especially if the content of the variables is user submitted. You should instead let the sqlite driver handle it as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute):

```
c.execute("SELECT Recipient, Sender, Subject, Message FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE ?) AND (Recipient LIKE ?)", (readdata, username))
```

Using `c.fetchone()` will retrieve only one result from this query without having to turn it into a list.

And affecting this result into all four variable at once avoid to unpack the tuple manually using indexes:

```
rec, sent, subject, msg = c.fetchone()
```

Your can simplify your code further by using only your first query, not having to perform a new one each time:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

con = sql.connect(r"E:\Users.db")
c = con.cursor()
con.row_factory = sql.Row
username = input("What is your username: ")

readdata = input("Select the message you wish to read: ")
c.execute("SELECT Recipient, Sender, Subject, Message FROM Mail WHERE (Subject LIKE ?) AND   (Recipient LIKE ?)", (readdata, username))

for rec, sent, subject, msg in c.fetchall():
    print()
    print("Sender: " + sent)
    print("Recipient: " + rec)
    print("Subject: " + subject)
    print()
    print("Message: " + msg)
```